# Put 2 NSAttributedStrings in one Label

Tags: ios, uitableview, label, nsattributedstring

is it possible to put 2 `NSAttributedString`s in only one label?

For example:

```
NSString *a =  [car valueForKey:@"name"];
NSString *b =  [car valueForKey:@"version"];

NSAttributedString *title;
    title = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:a attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy-Bold" size:36], NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @1 , NSStrokeColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]}]; //1

    NSAttributedString *title2;
    title2 = [[NSAttributedString alloc] initWithString:b attributes:@{ NSFontAttributeName : [UIFont fontWithName:@"Noteworthy-Bold" size:36], NSUnderlineStyleAttributeName : @0 , NSStrokeColorAttributeName : [UIColor blackColor]}]; //2

    cell.textLabel.attributedText = //what should I write here?
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the -appendAttributedString:(NSString *) method to append one attributed string to the other. Since you can make both of your attributed strings mutable, you can also include separators (semicolons, commas) to differentiate between your two different strings in the one label.

Here is some sample code:

```
NSMutableAttributedString *string1 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello"];
        NSMutableAttributedString *string2 = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@"Hello 2"];
NSMutableAttributedString *semiStr = [[NSMutableAttributedString alloc] initWithString:@" ; "];
[string1 appendAttributedString:semiStr]; //separate string 1 and 2 by semi-colon        
[string1 appendAttributedString:string2];

textLabel.text = string1; //which string2 is now appended to
```

Obviously, in your attributed strings, you would have attributes (like you stated in your question).
You can also always trust [Apple's documentation on the NSMutableAttributedString class](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSMutableAttributedString_Class/Reference/Reference.html) to find suitable methods to use next time.

Comment: But one thing doesn't work: When I set `[title appendAttributedString: @" ; "];` there is the following warning: `Incompatible pointer types sending NSString to parameter of type NSAttributedString`

Comment: ...and the the app crashes

Comment: @user2242550 My apologies - I wrote that code wrong. Answer will be edited to reflect proper code momentarily.

Comment: Let me explain _why_ that code didn't work. With `[string1 appendAttributedString:@" ; "]`, we're sending an NSString to an NSAttributedString. Those are two separate classes and are incompatible parameters. So, we can create the semicolon string in either an `NSAttributedString` object or an `NSMutableAttributedString` object, whichever you prefer. We then send that semicolon string to the `-[appendAttributedString:]` method, allowing the code to work again.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `NSMutableAttributedString` to either append the two attributed strings together or to build the attributed string and set the attributes at specified ranges (based on the source strings).

Comment: And how can I put both strings together?

Comment: The source strings are `NSString` so you could use `stringWithFormat` or `stringByAppendingString`. There are many options, you need to say what the result should be.